# ECSlidingViewControler will not reset top view after anchoring top view

Tags: ios, xcode, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I call `anchorTopViewToRightAnimated: onComplete:` and then call `resetTopViewAnimated:` in the completion block, but it doesn't reset. Everything else in the completion block executes fine. Even calling `anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:` and `resetTopViewAnimated:` right after one another doesn't reset the top view.